# Check day of week with php

Tags: php

I am trying to program a script that submits a form only on specific days of the week.

I have this code already.

```
date('w'); // gets day of week as number(0=sunday,1=monday...,6=sat)
    
// *note*: returns 0 through 6 but as string so to check if monday do this:
if(date('w') == 1){
    echo "its monday baby";
}
```

But I do not know if this is efficient enough.
Please is there a better way around this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the best approach for this task.
In case you want the name of the day, you can use the same fuction but a different param:

```
$day_name = date('l');
//$day_name = Monday. If lowercase is required, use strtolower().
```